# Not able to change value of hidden  input textbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying update some values for some hidden input boxes, but I'm not very successful.
I have no problem doing this to visible input[type=text].

Here is a small example: http://jsfiddle.net/saHCU/

*Use `Firebug` to see the hidden fields.*

You can see the value added to the text box for `item_id3`. But when you look at the source, none of the text boxes has an updated value.

Why is this not updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it does not change the attribute, but the underlying property.

The HTML `value` attribute can be considered more like a "starting point", what really matters is the property itself (`element.value = 1` in Javascript). If you try to submit your form, or query the value with Javascript, you will see that is has actually changed, **so your code is working fine**.

- [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) on StackOverflow

Also, as far as my knowledge goes, there is not `input type="textbox"`, only `input type="text"`.

Comment: So it doesn't matter if the input is hidden? `textbox` was just a typo, of course it is `text`. And is it a Firebug bug that the values are not shown in source? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Steven It does not matter at all. And again, it is not a bug. Firebug shows attributes, not properties. If you try to query the property from the console, you will see that it is actually set.